One of two LED Kitchen Light Fixtures Not Working on 3 way circuit
Recently replaced 2 older light fixtures in our kitchen. The one fixture was failing to light which we took to be the ballast which was too expensive to replace for this old fixture.  As a result we chose to replace both lights with new LED fixtures. Both are controlled by a 3-way switch one on each end of the kitchen. The first light we installed works fine from both switches.  The second, however, refuses to light though wired identically to the first. Fearing a bad fixture we returned it and replaced with another identical one, but the issue remains.  Test meter confirmed power at the box.  Could a wall switch still be the problem?

most probably a wiring problem which you say noting about

You tested the hot.  Did you test the neutral?  After all, you don't know that the wiring was functional before your changes.  Also, the hot shouldn't test pass/fail.  You should be able to measure a voltage potential.

They are not going to be wired identically. One of them will have switched hot from a switch plus neutral from somewhere (may travel with the switched hot or may travel with hot but split off on the way). That fixture will have a second cable which goes to the second fixture carrying switched hot and neutral. The second fixture only has one cable/wire pair, not two.
The only way they can be wired identically is if you have switched hot and neutral come from the switch box in two separate cables (or pairs of wires in conduit). That is not as common because it tends to be inefficient - usually the switch will be much closer to one light fixture than to the other one so you wire: panel -> switch 1 -> switch 2 -> light 1 -> light 2, though there are some variants.

On the fixture not working, by identical, I meant neutral was wired to neutral and positive to positive just has the old that was removed, with the ground wire attached to the box ground.  No changes were made to the any other connections in the ceiling box.  Also, wondering if going from florescent lighting to LED had any impacts?
